# Query spilling to disk

Tags: performance, disk, greenplum

We have a query which spills to disk (about 1 Terabyte!), here's the code:

```
WITH q (year,quarter) AS ( SELECT * FROM temp.quarters) SELECT *,
(SELECT price FROM prices WHERE EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM
pricing_date::TIMESTAMP) = q.quarter AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM
pricing_date::TIMESTAMP) = q.year ORDER BY pricing_date LIMIT 1) FROM
q ORDER BY q.year,q.quarter
```

the price table has millions of rows, is there a way to improve this query so that it doesn't spill too much? We think it may be due to the fact we're using the "With" clause and not temp tables?

Table definition below:

```
CREATE TABLE public.record_pricing (
    record_id int8 NOT NULL,
    pricing_date date NOT NULL,
    price numeric(26,10) NOT NULL,
    )
WITH (
    appendonly=true
);
```

There are no indexes, no constraints

Thanks,

Comment: Could you show us the results from EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)  ? And could you show us your table and index definitions as well? Without this information it's almost impossible to help you.

Comment: Sure thing, I'm running it now, will post it here as soon as I can

Comment: Which Postgres version are you using?

Comment: We're using 9.4.24, it's a Greenplum DB

Comment: Then try to remove the CTE. (which isn't really needed to begin with).

Answer (score 0):

The answer is already in your question

> There are no indexes, no constraints

To improve query time in such a large table, the usage of indexes are imperative. Try adding partial indexes to your table, so that the query planer knows beforehand where to find year and quarter, e.g.

```
CREATE INDEX idx_pricing_quarter ON record_pricing (EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM pricing_date::TIMESTAMP));
CREATE INDEX idx_pricing_year ON record_pricing (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM pricing_date::TIMESTAMP));
```

.. or even

```
CREATE INDEX idx_pricing_year_quarter ON record_pricing 
  (EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM pricing_date::TIMESTAMP) , 
   EXTRACT(YEAR FROM pricing_date::TIMESTAMP));
```

You might wanna consider indexing `pricing_date` as well, take a look at the [`documentation`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/indexes-ordering.html)

```
CREATE INDEX idx_pricing_date ON record_pricing (pricing_date);
```

Note that indexes may slow down `INSERTS` in your table! But since it is most likely a Data Warehouse, this might not be a problem.

After that your query should get significantly faster. The best way to see if your query is using the indexes properly is to `EXPLAIN` it. Play with it and you will see the improvements yourself.

Btw, the CTE isn't the issue here, since it is a full scan in a presumably small table `temp.quartes`, but if you wanna get rid of it try:

```
SELECT q.year,q.quarter,
 (SELECT price 
  FROM record_pricing 
  WHERE EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM pricing_date::TIMESTAMP) = q.quarter AND 
        EXTRACT(YEAR FROM pricing_date::TIMESTAMP) = q.year
  ORDER BY pricing_date LIMIT 1)
FROM quarters q;
```